# Spring boot Post calls are not working with NGINX

Tags: spring-boot, rest, nginx, web, webserver

I am running Spring boot application on port 9077.All API calls(GET,POST..) are working fine when I use the IP address.But only GET calls are working when I use the domain name.No POST call is working.I am getting 404 error.
This is my nginx config:

```
server {        
listen 80;        
listen [::]:80;  
server_name example.com;    

location / {             
       proxy_pass http://localhost:9077/; 
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;   
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      } 

 error_page  404     =200 $uri;
}
```

Comment: This is my spring boot application.properties :
server.port:9077
server.forward-headers-strategy: native
server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects: true

Comment: Try removing the last slash on the proxy_pass address location.
Should look like `proxy_pass http://localhost:9077;`.

Comment: I removed the last slash and restarted the nginx.Still POST calls are not working.

Comment: Ok, let's get deep, are you providing this infrastructure locally or in some cloud Linux VM?

Comment: I hosted my website  in Google Cloud Debian instance.

Comment: You have already tested you NGINX response by your domain? Accessing `yourdomainexample.com`, you should be able NGINX welcome page, also, shoud log the request in `/var/log/nginx`.